# How to append in a php string in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to append this `php` code using jquery. Is it possible?
I have

```
<script>
var myUrl = $("#categories").val();

   $("<?php include('" + myUrl + "') ?>").appendTo( ".imgList" );
</script>
```

Is that the correct way of doing it? or is it just impossible?
Any help is appreciated thanks.

**Edit**
This is the code I am using to load the content.

```
var myUrl = $("#categories").val();

 $( ".imgList" ).load(myUrl);
```

But it doesn't change when I change categories.

**Edit2**

```
                <select id="categories" name="categories">
                <option value="">Choose a category</option>
                <option value="page1.html">Real Estate</option>
                <option value="page2.html">Commercial Auto</option>
                <option value="page3.html">Beauty/Salon</option>
                <option value="4">Health</option>
                <option value="5">Construction</option>
                <option value="6">Legal</option>
                <option value="7">Furniture</option>
                <option value="8">Food</option>
            </select><!-- end id="categories" -->
```

Comment: You can't do that, `PHP` is for server side scripting, `JavaScript` is client side.

Comment: So you want to get the contents of `myUrl` and append it to `.imgList`? This can be done in jQuery/ajax, but has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: @adam Yes! That's exactly what I want. I was using the `.load()` function but it only shows the content when the page is loaded not when I change categories.

Comment: @adam I edited my question to the code I have right now but doesn't work when I change categories.

Comment: Because you haven't made it happen when someone triggers the change of category, you've just told it to run.

Comment: So I would have to add `If` statements? Sorry I am totally clueless on how to make the trigger events. :/

Comment: What type of element is #categories? Radio buttons? Can you post the HTML that will adequately describe what #categories is?

Comment: It is a dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#categories").on('change', function(){
    $( ".imgList" ).load( $(this).val() );
}).trigger('change'); // trigger 'change' on page load if you want to load categories based on whichever is selected by the HTML outputted
```

Comment: Yes that worked! I was tried using the `.change(fucntion() {` but didn't know how to write it right! Thanks a lot!.